# Fetching more shots using Jribbble

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, a question that I've been asking myself is how one should load more shots using the [jRibbble](https://github.com/tylergaw/jribbble) plugin. Sadly, I couldn't find anything on this subject that makes sense to me. I've only been using JavaScript for about a week now, so I apologize if this appears clumsy. My code so far is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // this is jRibbble example code if I recall correctly
    $.jribbble.getShotsByPlayerId('name', function (playerShots) {
        var html = [];

        $.each(playerShots.shots, function (i, shot) {
            html.push('<li><a href="' + shot.url + '">');
            html.push('<img src="' + shot.image_url + '" alt="' + shot.title + '"></a></li>');
        });

        $('#grid').html(html.join(''));
    }, {page: 1, per_page: 6});

    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
        window.shotHeight = $('#grid li').outerHeight(true);
    });
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + shotHeight > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
        // so that there's a time buffer between the time of request and when the user reaches the bottom of the page (and thus expects new posts)
    }
});
```

I don't think that it's necessary to mention how thankful I'd be if someone could at least provide some pointers.

Note: as I've already received a downvote I'd like to explain that I'd like to get some pointers, and not that I'm too lazy to code myself.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found the answer to my question. All I've to do is rerun the getShotsByPlayer, increasing the 'per_page' every time I do so. Then, just merge the two arrays. I should've known this.